Namenode Down showing out of memory error
We are trying to delete the snapshot but our namenode goes down showing error out of memmory
we have lots of snapshots directories on our cluster so we want to delete it for better cluster performance .

What is using all your memory? Have you tried freeing up some memory to address the memory issue? What have you tried so far?
